# Interface or class as method (or constructor) parameter

Tags: class, parameters, interface

Why do I have class or interface passed as a method parameter in a class? I don't get that concept. For example:

Declaration:

```
public void doSomething (Class yourClass){}
```

Calling the method:

```
doSomething(yourClass);
```

What is the benefit? Is there an alternative? I can't call methods for `yourClass` anyway, for example: `doSomething(yourClass.someMethod())` or `doSomething(yourClass)` and then `yourClass.someMethod()` are both invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There's several possibilites, depending on the particular language. `doSomething(Class)` could...

- Instantiate and return a Class generator.
- Create an object or service to track or otherwise interact with one or more Class objects.
- Return useful information about Class (e.g. via reflection).